# How to use a font awesome icon to react-table v7 with expand / contract?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, expand, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm attempting to use react-table and its expand/contract functionality, but can't figure out how to replace the icon given in the documentation.  I'm trying to use a font-awesome icon, but even with dangerouslySetInnerHTML I get a string, instead of the icon.  Here is the example in the documentation:  https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/sub-components

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/sub-components?file=/src/App.js:3192-3633

This is the block in question.  I can add a simple string to replace the fingers, by '>' and '^' but need to use a span icon (font awesome):

```
 {
        // Make an expander cell
        Header: () => null, // No header
        id: 'expander', // It needs an ID
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          // Use Cell to render an expander for each row.
          // We can use the getToggleRowExpandedProps prop-getter
          // to build the expander.
          <span {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps()}>
            {row.isExpanded ? '' : ''}
          </span>
        ),
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `span`. Should be `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={..} />`.
Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-tree-932eiz?file=/src/App.js) with `font awesome`. You must follow installation [steps](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react#using-icons). Post that -

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faAngleRight, faAngleUp } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

Cell: ({ row }) => (
// Use Cell to render an expander for each row.
// We can use the getToggleRowExpandedProps prop-getter
// to build the expander.
  <span {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps()}>
    {row.isExpanded ? (
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleUp} />
    ) : (
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
    )}
  </span>
)
```

Output -

[image: react-table with font-awesome]